# Python: pass statement in lambda form

Tags: python, lambda, anonymous-function

A Python newbie question, why is this syntax invalid: `lambda: pass`, while this: `def f(): pass` is correct?

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That is an error because after the colon you have to put the return value, so:

```
lambda: pass
```

is equal to:

```
def f():
   return pass
```

that indeed makes no sense and produces a `SyntaxError` as well.

Answer (score 57):

lambdas can only contain *expressions* - basically, something that can appear on the right-hand side of an assignment statement. `pass` is not an expression - it doesn't evaluate to a value, and `a = pass` is never legal.

Another way of thinking about it is, because lambdas implicitly return the result of their body, `lambda: pass` is actually equivalent to:

```
def f():
    return pass
```

Which doesn't make sense. If you really do need a no-op lambda for some reason, do `lambda: None` instead.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! But then, since `lambda: None` still returns a value, is there any way I can define an anonymous function that behaves exactly like `def f(): pass`?

Comment: @Rez it *is* actually the same - all Python functions return a value; if they fall off the end, or reach a bare `return`, they return `None`.

Answer (score 32):

The return value of a function without a `return` statement is `None`. You can see this from the simple `pass` function that is defined in the OP:

```
>>> def f():
...     pass
... 
>>> print f()
None
```

If you are looking for a lambda function that is equivalent to this "no-op" function, then you can use:

```
lambda: None
```

For example:

```
>>> f = lambda: None
>>> print f()
None
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use a lambda you could rely on the [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) literal `...`.

Your lambda would become `lambda: ...`.

The Ellipsis literal is often used instead of pass.